# Recursive Coin Change Making by printing all possible ways

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have tried to print all the paths which give the given amount. But my code does not work properly. I think I am missing some points to print all possible combinations. For example;

- if amount: 7 and startCoin = 25, the program needs to give me:
  {5,1,1} and {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}.

Can you help me to fix these problem?

Note: Preferably Java Solutions

```
class Solution {

      static int[] coinSet = {1,5,10,25};
      static List<List<Integer>> possibleWays = new ArrayList<>();
      static List<Integer> currentWay = new ArrayList<>();

      private static int makeChange(int amount, int startCoin){

        boolean flag = false;
        for(int i =0 ; i < coinSet.length ; i++){
          if(coinSet[i] == startCoin) {
            flag =true;
          }
        }

        if(!flag){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("startCoin has to be in the specified range");
        }

        int nextCoin = 0;
        switch(startCoin) {
          case 25:
            nextCoin = 10;
            break;

          case 10:
            nextCoin = 5;
            break;

          case 5:
            nextCoin = 1;
            break;

          case 1:
            possibleWays.add(currentWay);
            currentWay = new ArrayList<>();
            return 1;
        }

        int ways = 0;

        for(int count = 0; count * startCoin <= amount; count++){
          ways += makeChange(amount - (count * startCoin),nextCoin);
        }

        return ways;

      }    
      public int calculateNumberOfWays(int amount, int startCoin) throws Exception {
        if (amount == 0) {
          throw new Exception();    }

        return makeChange(amount, startCoin);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(makeChange(5,25));
        System.out.println(possibleWays);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you can have a look here for help: http://info.mcip.ro/?cap=Backtracking&prob=368 . It's not java but it solves your problem :).
If you are still confused study a bit about backtracking problems.

Comment: Do you have any idea what is the time complexity and space complexity of this solution? I guess it is O(n!) but I am not sure.

Comment: Regarding the complexity: You can avoid the exponential running time with *dynamic programming*. When you have all solutions for a value like 5, then the solutions for a value like 6 is (all solutions for 1) x (all solutions for 5).

Comment: What is the mean of exponential complexity? I try to understand what is the time complexity of the above code right now ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using backtracking but that is not very efficient, below is the working java code

```
/**
 * Created by sumit sharma on 3/1/2016.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static int[] coinSet = {1,5,10,25};
    static List<List<Integer>> possibleWays = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Integer> currentWay = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> countOfCoins = new ArrayList<>();
        makeChange(7, 0, countOfCoins);
        //System.out.print(possibleWays);
    }

    private static int makeChange(int amount, int startCoinIdx, List<Integer> coinsSoFar) {
        if(startCoinIdx == coinSet.length){
            if(amount == 0){
                possibleWays.add(coinsSoFar);
                System.out.println(coinsSoFar);
            }
            //System.out.println(coinsSoFar);
            return 0;
        }
        for(int count = 0;(count*coinSet[startCoinIdx]) <= amount;count++){
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0;i < coinsSoFar.size();i++) temp.add(coinsSoFar.get(i));
            for(int i = 0;i < count;i++) temp.add(coinSet[startCoinIdx]);
            makeChange(amount - (count * coinSet[startCoinIdx]),startCoinIdx+1, temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Link to solution on Ideone : http://ideone.com/kIckmG

Comment: As @marco13 suggested a dynamic programming solution is also possibel which wil be much more efficient but that would increase the amount of memory required or space complexity. Also note that the DP solution is not polynomial, instead it is what we call Pseudo-polynomial because it depends on the amount of memory required for a certain input.